# Fill ComboBox with DataTable result

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox

i'm trying to fill a combobox from a datatable result of a query, but it must have an empty first index and the displaymember should be concatenate

```
Public Function getAllSocios()
    Dim comanMySql As New MySqlCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable
    If My.Settings.bdCom Then
        comanMySql.Connection = conMySql
        comanMySql.CommandText = "SELECT id , name, last_name FROM usuarios ORDER BY n_socio"
        comanMySql.Parameters.Clear()
        Try
            comanMySql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(comanMySql)
            da.Fill(ds, "tabla")
            dt = ds.Tables(0)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Return dt
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine(cBDError & "Error en getAllUsers ")
            Trace.WriteLine(cMySqlError & ex.Source & " - " & ex.Message)
            Trace.Flush()
        End Try
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I tried to set the values by using a for loop, but i'm not able to set the valuemember
dinamically (must be the id value)

```
    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    socios = BD.getAllSocios
    For i As Integer = 0 To socios.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.combo_fam.Items.Add(socios.Rows(i).Item("id").ToString + " - " + socios.Rows(i).Item("name") + " " + socios.Rows(i).Item("last_name"))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like this

```
SELECT (Cast(id As varchar) + ' - ' + name + ' ' + last_name) As DisplayItem, Id FROM ...
```

then fill the table using that query.
To fill the blank item at the first row. use following code.

```
Dim row As DataRow = dtTable.NewRow()
row("DisplayItem") = "Enter Value or leave it blank"
row("ID") = -1
dtTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
```

Then bind the combobox with that datatable.

```
Combobox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayItem"
Combobox1.ValueMember = "Id"
Combobox1.DataSource = dtTable
```